# Connection Refused Error

Tags: xml, svg, xml-namespaces

I have the problem, if I try to parse a File, I get a connention refused error.
This is because I have no internet connection on the machine which runs the code, and I dont have the possibility to change that.

The header of the file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generator: Arbortext IsoDraw 7.2 -->
<svg id="Standardebene" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 135.413 119.471"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" xml:space="preserve">
```

So I can disable the .dtd loading with:

```
setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

It works, but I get another error from the namespace line.
I just could remove `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`
and it would work, too, but Im wondering if there are some better solutions for this?
I dont want to remove that line every time a .svg file is generated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What library/langueage are you using?

Comment: Sry forgot to mention, Im using java and the DocumentBuilderFactory for parsing.

Comment: try setValidating(false)